# Failed to open stream: no such file or directory error with behat

Tags: laravel, behat

I am attempting to develop some test for an app I inherited.  It is a laravel app and I have been trying to use behat because it reminds me of cucumber.  The problem is that behat is telling me a string is being displayed when it is not being displayed.

I have a success / failure test for logging in

Here is the scenario that is failing me

```
  Scenario: Log in with username and password and go to watercooler

  Given I am on "/auth/login"
  Then I should see "E-Mail Address"
  Then I should see "Password"
  Then I should see "Remember Me"
  Then I should see "Login"
  Then I should see "Register"
  Then I should see "Forgot Your Password?"
  Then I should not see "Errors"

  When I fill in the following:
      | email    | example@example.com |
      | password | password                 |
  And I press "Login"

  Then I should be on "/p/watercooler"
  Then the response should not contain "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."
```

Everything works up to the last line, however it keeps telling me that the text is being displayed on the page when it is not.

The exact error I am getting is

```
Then the response should not contain "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." # FeatureContext::assertResponseNotContains()
The string "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." appears in the HTML response of this page, but it should not. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ExpectationException)
```

If I add a line to search for text being displayed on the page that should be there, it tells me that text is there as well.

I have also tried

```
Then I should not see "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."
```

as well as

```
And I should not see "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."
```

and

```
And the response should not contain "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."
```

The error I am getting off of printing last response as suggested by morphatic the error I am getting is this

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(/Library/WebServer/Documents/.../public/build/rev-manifest.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php line 668
```

Every testing framework I have tried has thrown this error so much so that I recognized the line in the helpers.php file.

Do I need to somehow trigger gulp to run, or something?  I honestly have no idea how to fix this and have been struggling to find anything on the subject.

---

#### Solved

The answer was found after morphatic's answer.  When I used "And print last response"  I was able to get the text of the actual error that was happening and realized that it was following an incorrect path to my file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your test is working as you want it to work, and it is telling you that there's a problem with your code, or possibly with your testing configuration. Here are a couple of pitfalls when working with Behat:

1. I don't know how you have it setup, but in my apps, I have a separate `APP_ENV=acceptance` environment set up when I use Behat. I store all the config values for it in `.env.behat` ([here's an example app that demonstrates the configuration for testing with Behat](https://github.com/laracasts/Behat-Laravel-Extension-Example-App)).
2. Make sure you've set the `APP_KEY` for your `.env.behat`. If you forget that, you'll get an error even if your code is set up correctly.

Here's something that I do when I run into a situation like this. Add the line:

```
And print last response
```

Before the line in your scenario that is giving you trouble. Then you can actually see what error Behat is complaining about.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That "print last response" line is something I have been searching for to help try to debugg.  It looks like the error has to do with gulp, it is not finding rev-manifest.json file apparently.  I am updating question with new error.  It seems this is a setup thing perhaps?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually after looking through the wall of error text I was able to figure out it was looking at the wrong path.  Thanks again for your answer, it saved me a ton of time and helped me debug this.